# Is there an event which fires before a user enters a row into the datagridview in .net 3.5

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, datagridview, wrapper

I am trying to create a wrapper to replace the sheridan datagrid actvex control with a datagridview.

The sheridan datagrid control supports an event which fires just before the user is going to add a row to the grid called BeforeInsert.

Does anyone know of an equivalent event in the datagridview control or or some other code I could write which produces the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a look at all the events here, I don't see one for Adding or Inserting a row, just Added. Although there's one for Deleting and Deleted strangely enough. I won't pretend to know why. To your question, how exactly will users be adding rows? You could try playing around with the "AllowUserToAddRowsChanged" event and change that property programatically when the user wants to add a row.